# iOS - table view - static cells (grouped) - change section header text color

Tags: ios, uitableview

**Overview**

I have an iOS project with a table view with the following specification:

- **static cells** (content is not dynamically populated)
- style is grouped

**Question**

1. How can I change the text color of the section header of the static table view ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to create your own header view:

implement within your tableview datasource/delegate

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 6, 300, 30);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:(136.0/360.0)  // Slightly bluish green
                                 saturation:1.0
                                 brightness:0.60
                                      alpha:1.0];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    label.text = sectionTitle;

    // Create header view and add label as a subview

    // you could also just return the label (instead of making a new view and adding the label as subview. With the view you have more flexibility to make a background color or different paddings
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, SectionHeaderHeight)];
    [view autorelease];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You could just return the label, there is no benefit in adding it as a subview to an otherwise empty view.

Comment: Yes right.... but maybe you'd like to re-positioning your label or something like this...

Comment: thanks a ton !!!. When the label is returned directly, the label is NOT positioned at the X position 6.Based on my understanding, which ever view is returned, it's `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` is ignored. So when the label is added as a subview to the view and  the view is returned, then the label's `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` is preserved bcuz it is relative to it's super view.

Comment: Yes. That's why it make sense you use another `UIView` and place the `UILabel` as subview.

Comment: Very bad solution to create own view.

Answer (score 14):

Can make this too:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [[((UITableViewHeaderFooterView*) view) textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

.....

Answer (score 1):

I was able to view the header only after adding height for header along with the view

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 110;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4.2**:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.OMGColors.dimText
    }
}
```

No need to make your own header view - that defeats the purpose of static cells. I'm surprised you can't set this directly in IB somewhere though...